# sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError expression 'memberproductmapping' failed to locate a name

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, foreign-keys, relationship

base.py

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
Base = declarative_base()
```

Rules.py

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy import ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from datasource.driver.base import Base


class Rules(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'ruleengine'

    ruleenineid = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    bridge1 = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('memberproductmapping.bridgeid'))
    bridge2 = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('memberproductmapping.bridgeid'))
    # TODO do we have to keep track of table name and normalize it as its possible for integrity violation?
    table1 = Column(String(100, 'SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS'))
    table2 = Column(String(100, 'SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS'))
    # TODO do we have to keep track of column name and normalize it as its possible for integrity violation?
    column1 = Column(String(100, 'SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS'))
    column2 = Column(String(100, 'SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS'))
    entityid = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('entities.entityid'))

    memberproductmapping = relationship('memberproductmapping', foreign_keys=[bridge1, bridge2])
    entities = relationship('entities', foreign_keys=[entityid])
```

Config.py

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from datasource.driver.base import Base


class Config(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'config'

    config_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    db_name = Column(String(100, 'SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS'))
    server_name = Column(String(100, 'SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS'))

    def serialize(self):
        return {
            'config_id': self.config_id,
            'db_name': self.db_name,
            'server_name': self.server_name
        }
```

MemberProductMapping.py

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from datasource.driver.base import Base



class MemberProductMapping(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'memberproductmapping'

    bridgeid = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    memberid = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('member.memberid'))
    productid = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('product.productid'))
    configid = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('config.configid'))

    config = relationship('config', foreign_keys=[configid])
    member = relationship('member', foreign_keys=[memberid])
    product = relationship('croduct', foreign_keys=[productid])
```

When I try to get list of rules by

```
result = session.query(Rules).order_by(Rules.ruleenineid)
```

I got this error

> sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: When initializing mapper Mapper|MemberProductMapping|memberproductmapping, expression 'config' failed to locate a name ("name 'config' is not defined"). If this is a class name, consider adding this relationship() to the  class after both dependent classes have been defined.

I am not sure where is the problem. When I tried similar CRUD operation for simple tables(without FK reference) it worked fine.

I attached my schema diagram as well
[image]

Comment: and where is the declarative class / table `config` declared?! (I guess nowhere...) - that's not how SQLA works.

Comment: I have created all classes using declarative_base which is imported from base.py.
For simple classes like product and member I can do CRUD via sql alchemy. For classes with foreign key I got this error.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala can you give me an example?

Comment: What example? I asked where's the `class Config(Base):` of yours?

Comment: oops, added it in question. Thanks

Comment: Ah now I saw it (too tired). The names in `relationship`s should be names of the *declarative classes*, i.e. `Config`, `Member`

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Thanks.
I tried it before. Got sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: When initializing mapper Mapper|MemberProductMapping|memberproductmapping, expression 'Config' failed to locate a name ("name 'Config' is not defined"). If this is a class name, consider adding this relationship() to the <class 'model.MemberProductMapping.MemberProductMapping'> class after both dependent classes have been defined.

Comment: then, we have another error there: you're not actually *importing all of those model classes now, or are you?*

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154566/discussion-between-vinoth10-and-antti-haapala).